# CMD Isolated a Variable Inside a Variable

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

```
if [!PointX%N%:~1,1!] == [] (echo Good) Else (echo Bad!)
```

The Code kills the batch file and reads:

```
1!] was unexpected at this time.
```

The Full code is

```
echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a N=1
set /a R=1
:loop
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
if %R% EQU 1 (set /p Points=How many points do you have? ) ELSE (
echo You have %points% Total Points & echo You have %left% Points Left to Plot)
echo.
set /p PointX%N%=PointX%N% equals? 
set /p PointY%N%=PointY%N% equals? 
cls
if [!PointX%N%:~1,1!] == [] (echo Good) Else (echo Bad!)
pause
if %N% GEQ %R% (goto :Fin) ELSE (set /a N=%N%+1 & set /a R=2 & goto :loop)
:Fin
exit
```

Any Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`,` is a standard delimiter in batch - like the space.
Try with quotes - this will will enclose the expressions:

```
if "!PointX%N%:~1,1!" equ "" (echo Good) Else (echo Bad!)
```

Comment: Why does '[]' not work and ' "" ' does? can you explain that a little more please.

Comment: @BrettNelson, `""` have a special meaning in batch, everything between a pair of quotes is treated as a single string/path/item/argument; unquoted strings are split by the default delimiters _SPACE_, _TAB_, `,`, `;`, `=`; also special characters like `^`, `(`, `)`, `&`, `<`, `>`, `|` lose their particular meaning in between `""`; square brackets `[]` however are nothing but ordinary characters just like letters...

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to that makes more sense on why that works hope you have a great day / evening